# Split data into sub cubes in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Is there an easy way to take a numpy array of 3-d data, and split it into octants, or finer resolution. So with data something like

```
[[0,0,0], [1,0,0], [2,0,0], [3,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,2,0], [0,3,0] ...]
```

I want 8 arrays split along the 2,2,2 planes.
So the first sub array would have values which have x < 2, y < 2, z < 2, second x >= 2 && x < 4, y < 2, z < 2 etc
I need to go deeper eventually, splitting each sub array into more cubes recursively.

Is there a better way than just looping over the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use filter ...

```
filter(lambda m: all([m[0]<2, m[1]<2, m[2]<2]), xs)
```

to get your first quadrant ...

Now, since the plane is defined, the conditions are simply >2, <=2 an iterative split would be interesting. Lets say, you create a function that takes a list of points, and splits them according to a particular condition you supply ...

```
def fn1(pts , condition): 
    return [ filter( lambda m: condition(m), pts),  filter( lambda m: not condition(m), pts)  ]
```

Then, if you supply a condition to this for splitting along a particular plane ...

```
In [11]: fn1(xs, lambda m: m[0]<2)
Out[11]:
[[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0]],
 [[2, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0]]]
```

What you want is not this, but a function that takes a list-of-lists and splits according to the specified criterion, and returns another list-of-lists ...

```
def fn2(ptss, condition): 
    return reduce(lambda m,n: m+n, map(lambda m: fn1(m, condition), ptss))

In [15]: fn2( [ xs  ]  , lambda m: m[0]<2)
Out[15]:
[[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0]],
 [[2, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0]]]
```

But, you say, *this does the exact same thing!* Not quite. Now, you can supply a newly generated list and get another list. In case you had not come across this, it is something called *map-reduce* which is heavily used in both functional programming and big data.

```
xx = [xs]
xx = fn2(xx, lambda m: m[0]<2)
xx = fn2(xx, lambda m: m[1]<2)
xx = fn2(xx, lambda m: m[2]<2)

In [21]: xx
Out[21]:
[[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]],
 [],
 [[0, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0]],
 [],
 [[2, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0]],
 [],
 [],
 []]
```

As you will discern, the function `fn2` lets you *chain* results from your previous output directly to your next, to the same function. Also remember that functions in Python are first-class values, and you can have a list of functions ...

```
funcList = [lambda m: m[0] < 2, 
            lambda m: m[1] < 2, 
            lambda m: m[2] < 2]
```

I will leave you here, to come up with an elegant way of doing the chaining using the list of functions ...

Comment: Thanks - not come across this way of doing things before, will digest it.

Answer (score 0):

For the case of binary-splitting:

```
def binary_split(data):
    half_dims = [s/2 for s in data.shape]
    return np.array([data[s] for s in itertools.product(*[(slice(0, h), slice(h, 2*h)) for h in half_dims])]).reshape([2]*data.ndim+half_dims)
```

Hopefully that's cryptic enough.